# KNN algorithm implemented in Python

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, clustering

This is the first time I tried to write some code in Python.
I think it gives proper answers but probably some "vectorization" is needed

```
import numpy as np
import math
import operator

data = np.genfromtxt("KNNdata.csv", delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1)
data = data[:,2:]

np.random.shuffle(data)
X = data[:, range(5)]
Y = data[:, 5]

def distance(instance1, instance2):
    dist = 0.0
    for i in range(len(instance1)):
        dist += pow((instance1[i] - instance2[i]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(dist)

# Calculating distances between all data, return sorted  k-elements list (whole element and output)
def getNeighbors(trainingSetX, trainingSetY, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    for i in range(len(trainingSetX)):
        dist = distance(testInstance, trainingSetX[i])
        distances.append((trainingSetX[i], dist, trainingSetY[i]))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbour = []
    for elem in range(k):
        neighbour.append((distances[elem][0], distances[elem][2]))
    return neighbour

#return answer
def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = int(neighbors[x][-1])
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]

#return accuracy, your predicitons and actual values
def getAccuracy(testSetY, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(predictions)):
        if testSetY[x] == predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct / (len(predictions))) * 100.0

def start():
    trainingSetX = X[:2000]
    trainingSetY = Y[:2000]
    testSetX = X[2000:]
    testSetY = Y[2000:]

    # generate predictions
    predictions = []
    k = 4
    for x in range(len(testSetX)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSetX, trainingSetY, testSetX[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSetY, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: ' + str(accuracy))

start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a style nitpick: Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case_with_underscores` for variable and function names instead of `camelCase`.

Second, the comments you have above your functions should become [`docstrings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).
These appear for example when calling `help(your_function)` in an interactive session. Just Have a string as the first line below the function header like so:

```
def f(a, b):
    """Returns the sum of `a` and `b`"""
    return a + b
```

It is recommended to always use triple double-quotes (i.e. `"""`).

---

Now I am going to focus on the distance calculation.

First, you can greatly simplify your `getNeighbors` function using list comprehensions:

```
def getNeighbors(trainingSetX, trainingSetY, testInstance, k):
    distances = sorted((distance(testInstance, x), x, y)
                       for x, y in zip(trainingSetX, trainingSetY)
    return [(d[1], d[2]) for d in distances[:k]]
```

Here I used the fact that tuples already sort naturally, by first comparing the first index then (if they are equal) the second and so on. So I put the distance as the first index of the tuple and you don't need the key function any longer. `sorted` can take a generator expression and sort it directly. We can also iterate over multiple iterables at the same time using `zip`.

Since your variables are all numpy arrays, you could also do it more vectorized. For this I would first re-define the distance function to use numpy functions:

```
def distance(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(((x - y)**2).sum())
```

And then put the distances into a numpy array as well. Only returning the second and third column becomes then easier with array slicing.

```
def getNeighbors(trainingSetX, trainingSetY, testInstance, k):
    distances = np.array([(distance(testInstance, x), x, y)
                          for x, y in zip(trainingSetX, trainingSetY])
    distances.sort()
    return distances[:k, 1:]
```

This can probably be modified even further by trying to make the `distance` call vectorized as well.

---

Your function `classVotes` can be simplified using the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class which implements exactly what you do her:

```
def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = Counter(int(neighbor[-1]) for neighbor in neighbors)
    return max(classVotes.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Your function `getAccuracy` can be slightly simplified using a generator expression and `sum`:

```
def getAccuracy(testSetY, predictions):
    correct = sum(y == p for y, p in zip(testSetY, predictions))
    return correct * 100.0 / len(predictions)
```

And lastly, in your `start` function, you can directly iterate over the elements of `testSetX`, make it a generator expression and use the fact that `print` can take multiple arguments:

```
def start():
    trainingSetX = X[:2000]
    trainingSetY = Y[:2000]
    testSetX = X[2000:]
    testSetY = Y[2000:]

    # generate predictions
    k = 4
    predictions = (getResponse(getNeighbors(trainingSetX, trainingSetY, x, k)]
                   for x in testSetX)
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSetY, predictions)
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
```